# Contatenation of binary operators like "3 + + 2" in Matlab does not give errors

Tags: matlab, syntax, operators

If I evaluate this expression:

```
3 + + 2
```

or also

```
3 + + + + + + 2
```

I obtain `5` as the result.

If I also insert the `-` operator I also obtain a result (`1` in this case):

```
3 + - + - + - 2
```

I was thinking that the space between operators can be considered as zero, but if I use the times operator, I instead obtain an error:

```
3 * * 2 % Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

What's happening? What's the meaning of this syntax and why does it work with `+` and `-` but not with `*`?

Why this is valid syntax?

I'm using Matlab R2014a.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`+` and `-` can be binary or [unary](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uplus.html) operators. `*`  Can only be binary.

In your code, all `+` and `-` symbols after the first are probably being parsed as unary operators. So `3 + - 2` is interpreted as `3 + (-2)` (the `+` is binary, the `-` is unary). Similarly, `3 - + - 2` is interpreted as `3 - (+-2)`, that is, `3 - (-2)`.

That doesn't work with `*` because it cannot be a unary operator.

Comment: Once explained it makes a lot of sense, but the question baffled me in the beggining

Comment: @AnderBiguri What's REALLY baffling is that `3 + 2` is `5`, `[3 + 2]` is `5`, `3 +2` is `5`, but `[3 +2]` is `[3 2]`. Whitespace makes a difference to whether the operators are unary or binary, and in a really dumb way.